# Low p-value in test of uniformity of uniformly distributed data?

Tags: r, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

First we generated 10 numbers from a $U(0,1)$ then performed a Kolmogorov Smirnov test for q uniform distribution. Why is the p-value small?

```
> x=runif(10,0,1)
> x
 [1] 0.37010222 0.19008926 0.02689558 0.43170269 0.03485138 0.89168644 0.42372517 
  0.17899880 0.42714650 0.22280316
> ks.test(x,"punif")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.4683, p-value = 0.01567
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: The p-value generated by this way has a uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ (at least approximately) because you generate data under the null hypothesis. Hence your p-value is not unlikely, it is as likely as any other possible value in $(0,1)$.

Comment: What p-value did you get the *next* time you ran this code? Indeed, did you have to run the code several times before this small p-value appeared?

Answer (score 3):

Purely by chance, your values are unusually small -- only *one* of them is above 0.432.

[image]

About one time in 64, you should see a p-value at least as low as this if the data are from a uniform.

Here I generate 1000 such samples of size 10:

```
 pvals <- replicate(1000,ks.test(runif(10),"punif")$p.value)
```

In 15 of those samples, I got p < 0.01567:

[image]

which is close to what you'd expect. If 1000 people all do your exercise, you expect about 15 of them to get a p-value as low as that. Your sample is like those. You just happened to have an event that happens about 15.67 times in 1000 *by chance*.

Once in a while, you could toss a fair coin six times and get six heads. It doesn't mean the coin isn't fair.

Comment: Dear Glen wen we generate (in r) 10 numbers from a U(0,1) we expect all of them be iid from  U(0,1) but small p-value  in Kolmogorov Smirnov test  reject this fact.

Comment: When the null hypothesis is true, there's still a chance of getting a small p-value. If you generate 1000 samples of size 10, all from a standard uniform, in about how many of those samples should the p-value be $\leq$ .01567?

Comment: mohammad -- see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image of the estimated density of your sample.

[image]

```
x<-c(0.37010222, 0.19008926, 0.02689558,0.43170269 ,0.03485138, 0.89168644, 0.42372517, 0.17899880, 0.42714650, 0.22280316)
plot(density(x))
```

From this image, I think it's quite obvious why the p-value is so small. Because the sample that you happened to randomly generate doesn't look very uniform. If your sample size was larger, it would likely look more similar to uniform.

Comment: I would add: the reason for that is small sample size.

Comment: @Tim If by "that" you meant to refer to the p-value being small, I don't think that is so.  Surely the small sample size makes for visually apparent deviations from uniformity.  But if the p-values of the test are correctly calculated, then the chance of randomly obtaining a p-value of $0.01567$ or less is the same whether the sample size is $10$ or $10,000,000$.

Comment: No, I meant that small sample could easily deviate from the population distribution.